# TouchableHighlight not respecting state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `<TouchableHighlight>` component wrapping a `<Text>`, and onPress I am setting the state boolean to false to make it disappear. Works like a charm on iOS but on Android, the `<Text>` disappears but the `<TouchableHighlight>` is still rendered.

Any pointers?

```
{(this.state.showUpdateToast && this.state.updateCount > 0) ?
          (<TouchableHighlight 
            underlayColor='rgba(116, 59, 243, 1)' 
            style={styles.toast} 
            onPress={this.refresh.bind(this)}
          >
            <Text style={styles.toastText}>
              {this.state.updateCount}{this.state.updateCount < 2 ? this.props.getLabel('updateToastSingle') : this.props.getLabel('updateToast')}
            </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>) 
          : null
        }
```

Comment: Your child of a touchable should always be a View, they don't work so well with other elements, so wrap your Text in a View

Comment: I dont think that's it. And the issue is that <Touchable> does not unmount. The <Text> does.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post styles and refresh code.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply wrap your `TouchableHighlight` in a `View`. The `View` would be conditionally added and thus remove the touchable element with itself. That, assuming the `TouchableHighlight` is buggy as described.

Comment: The code looks good, Which RN version are you using? Also do you ensure  the state is changed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, but can you try something like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  underlayColor="rgba(116, 59, 243, 1)"
  style={[styles.toast, !(this.state.showUpdateToast && this.state.updateCount) && { opacity: 0 }]}
  onPress={this.refresh.bind(this)}
>
  <Text style={styles.toastText}>
    {this.state.updateCount}{this.state.updateCount < 2 ? this.props.getLabel('updateToastSingle') : this.props.getLabel('updateToast')}
  </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```